# Design UserControl Style with content in-between

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, wpf-controls

I've designed a style for a UserControl in various shapes eg Star, Ball, sky etc. All these shapes are designed using a path. I need read the content of the usercontrol using the style and adjust the width and height and display the content.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#CCC4C4" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
              <Path
           Data="F1M37.3,41.5L24.0,34.8 10.7,41.4 13.2,27.3 2.5,17.3 17.4,15.3 24.0,2.5 30.6,15.3 45.5,17.4 34.7,27.3 37.3,41.5z"
           Fill="White"
            Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
            Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
           Stroke="#FFC4A000"
           StrokeMiterLimit="4"
           StrokeThickness="1">

      </Path>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [ContentControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx), its a `Container` that can be filled with individual content.

Here's an example:

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#CCC4C4" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
              <Path
           Data="F1M37.3,41.5L24.0,34.8 10.7,41.4 13.2,27.3 2.5,17.3 17.4,15.3 24.0,2.5 30.6,15.3 45.5,17.4 34.7,27.3 37.3,41.5z"
           Fill="White"
           Stretch="Fill"
           Stroke="#FFC4A000"
           StrokeMiterLimit="4"
           StrokeThickness="1">

              </Path>
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
      <!-- the below ones become stars -->
      <ContentControl></ContentControl>
      <ContentControl></ContentControl>
      <ContentControl></ContentControl>
    </StackPanel>

  </Grid>
```

**EDIT:**

If you want the star to resize to its available space, use Stretch = Fill, instead of the with and height binding (changed that above).